# Not able to insert into MSSQL through grails application

Tags: sql, sql-server, grails

I cannot get my simple grails application to do an insert into my table through a user that I created, even though I was able to run the query in SQl management studio just fine.

I get this error:

```
The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'mini_user', database     'Mini_test', schema 'dbo'

InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [com.grailsinaction.MiniUser]; SQL [insert into mini_user (version, date_created, password, profile_id, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)];
```

I am able to run the above query in management studio without any errors.

Here is my Grails configuration, although the problem seems to be on the SQL server side.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
}    

test {
    dataSource {

        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/Mini_test;instance=SQLEXPRESS;user=tester2;password=tester2"
    }
```

I also placed the jtds-1.3.1.jar in "lib" (If I can figure this out, Ill probably switch to a maven dependency) and placed a runtime string in buildconfig.groovy.

```
  dependencies {

    runtime 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'

}
```

Here is my attempt to give "tester2" any and all access:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
I dont know what else to try. It seems like I have given that user unlimited access, so I'm not sure where these permission issues are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt look carefully enough at the permissions. I had "db_denydatareader" and "db_denydatawriter" checked. Very simple...

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are not specifying the database name in your conf file.

This is what mine looks like:

```
dataSource {
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server1:1433;databaseName=MyDbName"
        username = "user"
        password = "*******Pass"

        // logSql=true
    }
```

Also, make sure that the User Mapping has been set up in the Security at the Server level and not just under the security at the DB level.

Comment: I specified the database name as /Mini_test on the url string. According to the jtds documentation, that appears to be OK.                http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat